# NestJS Test Fails After Adding Transaction - Foreign Key Constraint Violation

Tags: postgresql, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a NestJS project using TypeORM and I'm facing an issue with my tests failing after adding a transaction. The error I'm getting is a foreign key constraint violation when trying to insert a new row into the project_group table. Here's the error message:

> QueryFailedError: insert or update on table "project_group" violates foreign key constraint "FK_a6e3f0560fc498dc3de01ee4250"

I'm using the runInTransaction function from typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked package in my service method like this:

```js
await runInTransaction(async () => {
  await RequestContext.impersonate(invite.user, async () => {
    await this.projectService.addProjectMember(
      project,
      invite.invitedEmail,
      invite.role
    );
  });
  await this.deleteInvite(invite);
});
```

And here's the addProjectMember method from project.service.ts:

```js
async addProjectMember(
  project: ProjectEntity,
  email: string,
  role = ProjectRole.Member
) {
  // rest of the code
  const member = await this.projectMemberRepository.save(projectMember);
  // rest of the code
}
```

I've checked that the ProjectMemberEntity that I'm passing to addProjectMember has a valid user with a valid email. I've also checked the logic where I'm handling the emailDomain and associating it with a projectId. There doesn't seem to be an issue there causing an invalid projectId to be used.

I've enabled logging of all queries and errors in TypeORM and I see that some delete operations are failing, but I don't see any rollback errors. Here are the logs:

```js
query: DELETE FROM "user"
query failed: DELETE FROM "user"
error: error: update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "FK_e7520163dafa7c1104fd672caad" on table "project_member"
```

I'm not sure why the transaction is causing the tests to fail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `user` table has a [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html) relationship with `project_member` table. Hence deleting the row from `user` table is violating the contraint and throwing the above mentioned error.

You can configure the foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE` (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)). Doing this, if you run the DELETE query, which will delete the row from `user` table along with the row referencing it in `project_member`